# How to continue using the currently running Firefox after updating it on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint

Previously (at most 1 year ago) updating Firefox was easy. Firefox was automatically or manually updated from the official repository and I could still use my currently running Firefox instance. I would get that new installed version of Firefox only after I manually chose to restart old-Firefox.

Unfortunately at some point this behavior changed. Now after update Firefox refuses to open new pages, is informing that it was updated and should be restarted, while promising to make the restart painless (which is a lie: text I wrote in text fields is gone, page scrolling is forgotten, youtube videos don't remember where I was, etc), and then at some point actually closes without asking.

This "we are forcing you to restart your software when we want and not when it's convenient for you" approach is very Microsoftish. I hate it!

Is there any way to disable this abhorrent behavior and return the good old Firefox behavior back?

Currently, when choosing between updating at Firefox's schedule or not updating at all, I choose the latter. Obviously, this is not optimal in terms of features or even plain security...

Answer (score -1):

If you update Ff and decide to run it as if it is an older version, then it will have some unxepected behaviour. You can disable automatic updates, keep using the older version and whenever it is you feel like upgrading, do so. Once you have upgraded Ff it needs to be restarted.

Comment: The thing is, this is a recent behavior. I was able to use the old version of FF without any problems for many years before that.

It's also possible to use the old/current version of other software. That's the beauty of Linux. Or suppose to be...

Comment: Yes, the way the software updates and what happens after that has changed. In fact, you will be forced to restart it at some point or it will exhibit strange behaviour. So my answer only reflects how you can best deal with this new reality. This paradigm is practiced by a number of large software types, including Windows 10, which will force a restart on you after a while after an update.